# Determine odd or even in a list, return results to a new list

Tags: python

The exercise I have is asking me to determine if each number of a list is even or odd, then to return the result in a new list named is_even.

My code

```
num_lst = [3, 20, -1, 9, 10]
is_even = []
for n in num_lst:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = is_even.append(bool(n))
    else :
        is_even.append(bool(0))
print(is_even)
```

It works, but is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: It's a one-liner with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Bit-wise operators are preferred for even/odd detection:

```py
num_lst = [3, 20, -1, 9, 10]
is_even = [not num & 1 for num in num_lst]
print(is_even)
```

Numbers that are odd have their least significant bit set so use `& 1` to mask to just that bit. `not` conveniently coerces to boolean and inverts the results.

Comment: Thanks Ouroborus, bitwise will come in a 2 or 3 weeks time I guess. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, you are checking the value of a boolean expression, `n % 2 == 0`, which will evaluate to either `True` or `False` depending on `n`. Then, there is no need to say "if true, then append `True`, and if false, then append `False`. So, a slight rewording of your existing code is to directly call `is_even.append(n % 2 == 0)` in your for loop:

```
for n in num_lst:
    is_even.append(n % 2 == 0)
```

This can be further shortened using a list comprehension, as per @marcdtheking's answer, into something like:

```
is_even = [n % 2 == 0 for n in num_lst]
```

---

**Side note:** At some point in your code you are appending `bool(n)`, with `n` being your list element. So basically you are converting your number into a boolean. This can be error prone, e.g. if `n` is zero, `bool(0)` is `False`, while zero is an even number. Why not using `True` and `False` instead of `bool(n)` and `bool(0)`?

Comment: Thank you Anis. I just recalled that in bool (0) is always False, but of course with 3 weeks of Python, I'm struggling a bit although I enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't learned about list comprehensions yet, your code is perfectly fine.  You can simplify it slightly by simply using True and False. Also see the answer by Anis.

```
num_lst = [3, 20, -1, 9, 10]
is_even = []
for n in num_lst:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = is_even.append(True)
    else :
        is_even.append(False)
print(is_even)
```

Comment: I did, but still struggling to understand it correctly. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, use a list comprehension

```
>>> num_lst = [3, 20, -1, 9, 10]
>>> is_even=[bool(0) if i % 2 else bool(i) for i in num_lst]
>>> print(is_even)
[False, True, False, False, True]
```